# Writing a Regex for finding a pattern from one arbitrary string in another

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to a regex to find similar "order-preserving" pattern/words found in "field" and use that to find matches in "text". I want to write such a regex that will find partial matches too like in Example 1 below.

Maybe, making words optional is an approach but then it starts to match arbitrary stuff.

**I want you folks help in trying to write a regex that takes "field" and makes a regex out of it and then finds that pattern in "text". Partial matches are okay, too.**

Both string inputs can be anything and regex should be generic enough to work on anything.

Please ask clarifying questions if needed!
Any observations/directions where I'm going wrong that you can point out would be very helpful.

```py
def regexp(field, text):

    import re
    
    key = re.split('\W', field)
    regex= "^.*"
    for x in key:
        if len(x)>0:
            #regex += "("+x+")?"
            regex += x
            regex += ".*"

    regex = r'{}'.format(regex)
    pattern = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
    matches = list(re.finditer(pattern, text))
    print(matches, "\n", pattern)

    if len(matches)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Examples:

```py
print(regexp("F1 gearbox: 0-400 m","f1 gearbox")) # this should match
#this is a partial match, my regex should be able to find this match

print(regexp("0-100 kmph" , "100-0 kmph")) # this should not match
#order of characters/words in my regex/text should match

print(regexp("F1 gearbox: 0-400 m","none")) # this should not match
#if i try use "(word)?" in my regex then everything becomes optional #and it starts to match random words like "none","sbhsuckjcsak", etc. #this obviously is not expected. 

print(regexp("Combined* (ECE+EUDC) (l/100 km)","combined ece eudc")) #this should match
#because its a partial match and special characters are not important #for my matching usecase
```

Comment: you should provide more examples, the ones you provide can be solved without regex. what about `print(regexp("F1 foo gearbox: 0-400 m","f1 gearbox"))`, should it match? and `print(regexp("F1 gearbarbox: 0-400 m","f1 gearbox"))`?

Comment: shorter `return len(matches)>0`

Comment: you set values in wrong order - you have `def regexp(field, text):` but you use it as `def regexp(text, field):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is already returning the right values for the examples you posted. You just have to fix the order of "text" and "field". I also made the code shorter and (in my opinion at least) easier to read:

```
def regexp(text, field):

    import re
    
    key = re.split('\W', field)
    regex = rf'^.*{".*".join(key)}'
    pattern = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
    # print(matches, "\n", pattern)

    return len(matches)>0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! for this neat and efficient code! I was aware that "field" and "text" seems out of order but I was try to do it that way. But it seems the only way to make it work is to swap them because you try to find a "smaller pattern" in a "bigger text body"

Comment: Well you can still define `regexp(field, text)` but you'll have to call `regexp("f1 gearbox", "F1 gearbox: 0-400 m")`. Sorry if this seems obvious, I'm not entirely sure what you mean...